# What platform to use in Azure for asp.net + wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure

I am working on a Azure school project in a university in Sweden, we have been divided in 6 groups.

Each group will recieve an Azure account, and is in charge of creating a .net page that consumes wcf services.

Each group also needs to host wcf services that can be consumed by another group on another azure account.

i.ex. Group 1 has a .net page that consumes a service that the group owns, Service 1. Now group 2 needs to consume Service 1 on their .net page. (Think SOA and each service is on its own Azure account)
Also Group 1's service makes sql querys to Group 3's sql database.

Should we use Web sites or Cloud services ?

Basicly we've had no education in Azure, only in c#, asp.net and wcf.

Is Service bus something we should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with Web Sites, it would be a lot easier and it would fit your needs.

No service bus needed unless you want to reach a local network computer from your cloud served site (or other)

**Edit**: What you will host on the Azure Web Site will be a regular ASP.net app with WCF services, just as you would in your local server. If you need to consume WCF services, the other group needs to tell you their url, and you will have to do the same to provide services.

Comment: Ok! but is it possible for a web site on another azure account to consume my wcf services that i have in web sites ? and how is that done? just reference like usual ?

Comment: added a little more explanation, you really need to go read the documentation on azure web sites

Comment: One caveat - with a cloud service/web role you have the option of using remote desktop for debugging purposes.  I agree that in production web sites provides for less management overhead and better source control integration.

Comment: With Azure Web Sites you get real-time remote debugging. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/, and I could be wrong but I'm pretty positive you also get Remote Desktop